# Using Elasticsearch Nest library throws error when creating a token Filter on index

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I need to create a Synonym token filter in Elasticsearch using the Nest library, but it keeps throwing an error.

```
     SynonymTokenFilter synonymFilter = new SynonymTokenFilter {
                    Format = SynonymFormat.Solr,
                    SynonymsPath= "synonym.txt",
                    Tokenizer="whitespace",
                };
isettings.Analysis.TokenFilters.Add("mysynonym",synonymFilter);
 isettings.NumberOfReplicas = 1;
            isettings.NumberOfShards = 2;

            IndexState indexConfig = new IndexState
            {
                Settings = isettings,
            };
```

everything else works if i comment out this line  `isettings.Analysis.TokenFilters.Add("mysynonym",synonymFilter);`

it throws a "object not set to an instance of an object" error.

I really need help with this, this is my first time use the Nest Library

I'm using ElasticSearch 6 and the latest version of the Nest Library.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like either `Analysis` on `isettings`, or `TokenFilters` on `isettings.Analysis` is null. Here's an example that works

```
var isettings = new IndexSettings
{
    Analysis = new Analysis
    {
        TokenFilters = new TokenFilters()
    }
};

SynonymTokenFilter synonymFilter = new SynonymTokenFilter
{
    Format = SynonymFormat.Solr,
    SynonymsPath = "synonym.txt",
    Tokenizer = "whitespace",
};
isettings.Analysis.TokenFilters.Add("mysynonym", synonymFilter);
isettings.NumberOfReplicas = 1;
isettings.NumberOfShards = 2;

IndexState indexConfig = new IndexState
{
    Settings = isettings,
};

var client - new ElasticClient();

client.CreateIndex(new CreateIndexRequest("index", indexConfig));
```

which creates the following JSON request

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/index
{
  "settings": {
    "index.number_of_replicas": 1,
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "mysynonym": {
          "synonyms_path": "synonym.txt",
          "format": "solr",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "type": "synonym"
        }
      }
    },
    "index.number_of_shards": 2
  }
}
```